# Where to double-check attributes of the XACML-request against Attribute-Providers at the PDP?

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, pdp, authzforce

I'm evaluation PDP engines and at the moment I give [AuthzForce Core](https://gitlab.ow2.org/authzforce/core/tree/master#authzforce-core-community-edition) a try. Evaluating a Request by the PDP runs pretty solid so far:

```
//My request and pdp configuration files
File confLocation = new File("D:/docs/XACML/AuthZForce/IIA001/pdp.xml");//pdp.xml tells the pdp where the policies xml files are
File requestFile = new File("D:/docs/XACML/AuthZForce/IIA001/Request.xml");

//I instantiate the pdp engine and the xacml parser
final PdpEngineConfiguration pdpEngineConf = PdpEngineConfiguration.getInstance(confLocation, null, null);
PdpEngineInoutAdapter<Request, Response> pdp = PdpEngineAdapters.newXacmlJaxbInoutAdapter(pdpEngineConf);
XmlUtils.XmlnsFilteringParser xacmlParserFactory = XacmlJaxbParsingUtils.getXacmlParserFactory(false).getInstance();

//I parse the request file
Object request = xacmlParserFactory.parse(requestFile.toURI().toURL());
if (request instanceof Request) {
    //At this point I could access all request attributes or alter them

    //I let the PDP evaluate the request
    Response response = pdp.evaluate((Request) request);

    //I check the results inside the response
    for (Result result : response.getResults()) {
                    if (result.getDecision() == DecisionType.PERMIT) {
                        //it's permitted!

                    } else {
                        //denied!
                    }
    }
}
```

Now, according to the literature like [[1]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3846525219) I should not trust the attributes in the given request-xacml-file. Whenever possible, I have to check against a Attribute Provider (e.g. a Patient database) if the given attributes (e.g. patient birthdate) actually belong to the patient in order to prevent attacks.

Otherwise the attacker could make the patient younger in the Request in order to access the patient's record as a parent guardian.

**Questions**

1. Is checking Requests against Attribute Providers the task of a PDP or of another entitiy?
2. Did OASIS specify anything concrete about that issue? E.g. workflow or syntax of configuration files
3. Is there a way to make my pdp engine aware of Attribute Providers?
4. Should I just check the provided request on my own before `Response response = pdp.evaluate((Request) request);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I don't know for other XACML implementations, but regarding AuthzForce, Attribute Providers play the role of *PIPs* in official XACML terms (see the definition of PIP in [XACML spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html)'s *Glossary*), i.e. responsible for getting any additional attribute that is not in the XACML request context (it usually means they are not provided by the PEP originally), whenever the PDP needs it to evaluate the policy. This relates to steps 5-8 of XACML standard data-flow model (§3.1 of [XACML 3.0 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html)). Besides, if you read the [XACML spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html) carefully, you notice that the actual entity calling the PIPs for the PDP is the so-called *context handler*. In practice, this is a matter of implementation, the *context handler* can take many forms. In AuthzForce, it is just a sub-component of the PDP, but you might have one on the PEP side as well which is application-specific, especially in a typical ABAC/XACML scenario where the PDP is a remote  service from the PEP's perspective, and the PDP is possibly talking to many PEPs in completely different application environments.
2. As mentioned previously, for the workflow, look at section 3.1 *Data-flow model* in the [XACML core spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html). For the syntax, XACML core specification defines a syntax for policies, authorization decision requests and responses, nothing else at this point. You may find other things in XACML Profiles, but no such thing as configuration syntax, to my knowledge.
3. In AuthzForce, the PDP engine is made aware of Attribute Providers by the PDP configuration, i.e. the `pdp.xml` file in your example. You'll need two other files (XML catalog and schema) depending on the Attribute Provider you want to use. This is documented in the [Using Attribute Providers section of AuthzForce Core's wiki](https://github.com/authzforce/core/wiki/Attribute-Providers).
4. Your code seems like test code to me since you are getting the xacml request from a local file so it seems you have full control over it, so no need to check further. More generally, it depends on the actual use case, really, no universal rule for that. Some attributes (like a subject-id resulting from authentication) are specific and only known by the PEP in its own app environment, so they are the responsibility of the PEP. Some other attributes are more likely the responsibility of the PDP (through attribute providers) if they can be resolved in a central way, such as attributes in a company's directory or other kind of identity repository.

Comment: I assume you mean this document: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html

Comment: It's always nice to get the answer from first hand! Thank you cdan. What you said is very true: _"More generally, it depends on the actual use case, really, no universal rule for that."_ In order to design a suitable implementation I have to learn more about your specific implementation of the PDP. That's why I asked a follow-up question in your github repo: https://github.com/authzforce/core/issues/17

Comment: Yes, I meant this doc. Sorry I was in a hurry at the time. I have now edited my answer with the proper link.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @cdan's excellent response, here are a few more pointers:

> Is checking Requests against Attribute Providers the task of a PDP or of another entitiy?

The PDP always trusts the information (attributes) it receives whether it be from the PEP or from the PIPs. As such the PDP need not verify values it received from a PEP by checking with a PIP. That's counter-productive an inefficient. If you cannot trust the PEP to send the right value, how can you trust it to enforce the right decision?

> Did OASIS specify anything concrete about that issue? E.g. workflow or syntax of configuration files

No, we did not. PIP behavior is outside the scope of the XACML spec.

> Is there a way to make my pdp engine aware of Attribute Providers?
>   Should I just check the provided request on my own before Response response = pdp.evaluate((Request) request);?

The PDP should be configured with PIPs. The PDP will use all the PIPs it can.

Comment: I think you've got to replace the first "PEP" with "PDP" in the following sentence, am I right? _"As such the PEP need not verify values it received from a PEP by checking with a PIP."_